I read a PDF file using Python, and part of the content is displayed as a string of garbled text. How should I restore it?
I read a PDF file using Python, and part of the content is displayed as a string of garbled text. How should I restore it?
import fitz
doc = fitz.open("2303.11366v4.pdf")# download from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.11366
print(doc[2].get_text().split('Figure 1')[0])

I got this text:
<RXDUHLQWKHPLGGOHRIDURRP 
>@7DVNFOHDQVRPHSDQDQGSXW 
LWLQFRXQWHUWRS
'HFLVLRQPDNLQJ
7DVN<RXDUHJLYHQDOLVWRIWZR 
VWULQJV>@RIRSHQ

RUFORVH 


SDUHQWKHVHVRQO\>@
3URJUDPPLQJ
7DVN:KDWSURIHVVLRQGRHV-RKQ 
/DQFKHVWHUDQG$ODQ'HDQ)RVWHU 
KDYHLQFRPPRQ"
5HDVRQLQJ
>@
$FWLRQWDNHSDQIURPVWRYHEXUQHU
2EV1RWKLQJKDSSHQV>@
$FWLRQFOHDQSDQZLWKVLQNEDVLQ
2EV1RWKLQJKDSSHQV>@
7KLQN>@QRYHOLVWMRXUQDOLVW 
FULWLF>@QRYHOLVW 
VFUHHQZULWHU>@FRPPRQLV 
QRYHOLVWDQGVFUHHQZULWHU
$FWLRQ²QRYHOLVWVFUHHQZULWHU³
GHIPDWFKBSDUHQVOVW
LIVFRXQW

 
VFRXQW

  VFRXQW

 
VFRXQW

>@
UHWXUQ
1R
6HOIJHQHUDWHGXQLWWHVWVIDLO
DVVHUWPDWFKBSDUHQV
(QYLURQPHQW%LQDU\5HZDUG

5XOH/0+HXULVWLF
+DOOXFLQDWLRQ
>@IDLOHGEHFDXVH,LQFRUUHFWO\ 
DVVXPHGWKDWWKH\ERWKKDGWKH 
VDPHPXOWLSOHSURIHVVLRQV>@ 
DFFXUDWHO\LGHQWLI\LQJWKHLU 
SURIHVVLRQV
>@ZURQJEHFDXVHLWRQO\FKHFNV 
LIWKHWRWDOFRXQWRIRSHQDQG 
FORVHSDUHQWKHVHVLVHTXDO>@ 
RUGHURIWKHSDUHQWKHVHV>@
>@WULHGWRSLFNXSWKHSDQLQ 
VWRYHEXUQHU>@EXWWKHSDQ 
ZDVQRWLQVWRYHEXUQHU>@
>@
UHWXUQ
<HV
LIFKHFN6RU 
FKHFN6HOVH
1R
7KLQN>@6RWKHSURIHVVLRQ 
-RKQ/DQFKHVWHUDQG$ODQ'HDQ 
)RVWHUKDYHLQFRPPRQLVQRYHOLVW
$FWLRQ²QRYHOLVW³
>@$FWLRQWDNHSDQIURP
VWRYHEXUQHU
>@2EV<RXSXWWKHSDQLQ 
FRXQWHUWRS
F
(YDOXDWLRQ
G
5HIOHFWLRQ
H1H[W
7UDMHFWRU\
E
7UDMHFWRU\
D7DVN
LQWHUQDOH[WHUQDO


I tried various different Python packages, but all of them resulted in garbled text.
It seems AI could recognize what does this text says.
1. <RXAREINTHEEMIDDLEOFAROOM> - You are in the middle of a room.

2. [TASKCLEANSOMEDANANDPUTITINCOUNTERTOP] - The task is to clean a pan and put it on the countertop.

3. [DECISIONMAKING] - This section is about decision making.

4. [TASKYOUAREGIVENALISTOFTWOSTRINGSOFOPEN ORCLOSEPARENTHESESONLY[]] - The task is to work with a list of two strings of open or close parentheses.

5. [PROGRAMMING] - This section is about programming.

6. [TASKWHATPROFESSIONDOESJOHNLANCHESTERANDALANDEANFOSTERHAVEINCOMMON?] - The task is to determine what profession John Lanchesterand Alan Dean Foster have in common.
.....

This text is from claude haiku.
But I need translate the text to human language with python.

This can be a very common problem usually associated with poor CID fonts. If you analyse the PDF there are 4 similar references to this one.
/Font << /G1 200 0 R /G2 201 0 R /G3 202 0 R /G4 203 0 R >>
200 0 obj
<< /Type /Font /Subtype /Type0 /BaseFont /AAAAAB+font000000002a1566ab
/DescendantFonts [ 205 0 R ] /Encoding /Identity-H
/ToUnicode 206 0 R >>
endobj

So it should be simple to convert page text stored as binary numbers from digits to ABC. Unfortunately something deleted the True Mapping (it is truncated) so there is no way to know which number is which letter.
Let's see what numbers have been stored as per that entry.
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo <<
  /Registry (Adobe)
  /Ordering (UCS)
  /Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000><FFFF>
endcodespacerange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end

So there is no conversion from page to font. Just a signal that it is 16 bits from 0 to 65536. No real use at all.
The text is stored in the page as:
003c0052005800030044005500480003004c005100030057004b004800030050004c00470047004f00480003005200490003004400030055005200520050

which using PyThon or other textual reader should convert to:
<RXDUHLQWKHPLGGOHRIDURRP

Thus that is the true text as written into the PDF.
The AI seems to have recognised the problem and converted the wrong numbers into something else perhaps OCR? But if so why capitals the text is clearly lower case. This is wrong.
 <RXAREINTHEEMIDDLEOFAROOM

However you can do better by providing Human intelligence and write a text parser to convert the wrong coding into good.
Replace 0003 WITH 0020 or spacebar that is a numeric increase by decimal +29. Now we start to see a word pattern
<RX DUH LQ WKH PLGGOH RI D URRP

Replace each number by add decimal 29 and convert to text
0044 with a
0048 with e
004c with i
0052 with o
0058 with u
and you should see a pattern emerge
003c o u  a 0055 e   i 0051  0057004b  e     0050  i 00470047004f  e       o 0049      a     0055  o   o 0050

add a sprinkling more and now its
003c ou are in 0057004b e midd 004d e of a room 

You should be able to map all the letters for that missing font CMap simply by adding 29 to the source data. And the same for the other three. With luck they are all the same missing letters, and the same common shift.
Generally this is a similar pattern fail in many PDF files. So you save your map and try it in other files with a similar problem. Which is why AI probably gets it wrong. Since it does not use intelligence to see that 0003 is a space character needing increase from \x03 to \x20 whilst the others are sometimes a different shift in values. Also it is not always the same shift for punctuation ranges.
Clearly if you have an Editor that provides bulk remapping (not the one shown I used a commercial PDF font Re-Mapper) then it is far easier to supply a replacement CID CMAP. Then the numbers will make more sense when viewed or extracted.
1 begincodespacerange
  <0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange

100 beginbfchar
<0001> <001E>
<0002> <001F>
<0003> <0020>
<0004> <0021>
<0005> <0022>
<0006> <0023>
<0007> <0024>
<0008> <0025>
<0009> <0026>
<000A> <0027>
<000B> <0028>
<000C> <0029>
<000D> <002A>
etc......

However not all numbers are "increased" some have "parity" and some have reduction so a simple renumber does not always work.
...
<009C> <009C>
<009D> <009D>
<009E> <009E>
<009F> <009F>
<00A0> <00A0>
<00B2> <0022>
<00B3> <0022>
endbfchar


Considering that last pair, perhaps they could possibly be <201C> (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK)  and <201D> (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK). As seen in ²QRYHOLVW³.
